# StringLengh Data Annotation using a static property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'd like to use the StringLength Attribute on an Entity, but instead of using a literal or a constant, to use a static property.

e.g

```
[StringLength(MyClass.MyStaticProperty)]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

However this results in the following error...

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

... has anyone got a work around or an alternative, other than using a string literal or constant?

In case you're wondering why a static property? The static property will return a value from an injected singleton.  The value will be injected at startup of the application.

Thanks... and Merry Christmas...

Answer (score 3):

Creating your own attribute is probably the best solution. You can then also take control over any other logic you might want to implement later.

```
public class CustomStringLength: ValidationAttribute
{
    public CustomStringLength()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return (string)value.Length == MyClass.MyStaticProperty;
    }
}
```

Considering `MyClass.MyStaticProperty` is an `int`.

Usage:

```
[CustomStringLength]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't think this works, the attribute will only be known the first time an instance of the class is created, I'm gonna test it, it's an interesting approach :)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck If it doesn't work, share a piece of code and let me know. We can work it out together :)

Comment: Will the Entity Framework use this validation?  Or does this only help with using the Entity within MVC forms?

Answer (score 1):

`StringLength` attribute parameter should be known at **compile time**.

You can either specify the exact value or refer to a constant value:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public const int MyStaticProperty = 5;
}

[StringLength(MyClass.MyStaticProperty)]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Note that there is no `static` keyword, since `const` implies `static`.

Comment: I don't think using a `const` solves the problem; *The static property will return a value from an injected singleton. The value will be injected at startup of the application.*

Comment: @DionV. It is not possible to use dynamic values in attribute constructor. If that's what the OP actually wants, then he should use your approach :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev doesn't seem like a natural constraint that the entity framework needs to know the length of a field at compile time.